# How to disable swipe gesture to go back when interacting with victory chart

Tags: ios, react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

I have created a victory chart in react native using Victory Native package. I have an interaction where the user can drag a vertical cursor to know about detail at different data points. This chart stretches the entire width of the screen.

The issue with ios is that ios by default has swipe left from right side of the screen to go back to previous screen. Now when the user starts to drag the cursor close to the right end of the screen this action to go back also happens.

Is there a way to stop this from happening if the user is interacting with the chart?

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can disable the ```swipeGestureEnabled={false}``` in your screen when you have define the navigation.